# How to generate XML for Menu using Dataset and display menu and menu items

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, menu

I need to generate a menu based on the values in the table/ dataset. The table contains data similar to the Image data below. The main menu contains 4 values, Products, Applications, Documents, Support. Each menu has its menu items.

[image: Menu and MenuItems]

[image]

Below is the sitemaster code for the master page:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" BackColor="#0072c5"
 CssClass="Menu" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px"
 ForeColor="#F7F6F3" Width="100%" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Orientation="Horizontal"
 StaticDisplayLevels="2">
 <DataBindings>
    <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" NavigateUrlField="NavigateUrl"  TextField="Text" ToolTipField="ToolTip" />
 </DataBindings>
</asp:Menu>
 <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" TransformFile="~/Default2.xslt" XPath="MenuItems/MenuItem"runat="server"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

I generated XML as below.

```
<Menus ProductName="Acapella Admin">

    <Menu MenuID="1" Text="Products">
    <MenuItem MenuID="1" Text="ProductInfo"  URL="ProductInfo.aspx"/>
    <MenuItem MenuID="2" Text="Product Features"  URL="ProductFeatures.aspx"/>
    <MenuItem MenuID="3" Text="Products Details" URL="ProductDetails.aspx" />
    </Menu>

   <Menu MenuID="1" Text="Applications">
    <MenuItem MenuID="1" Text="MobileApps"  URL="MobileApps.aspx"/>
    <MenuItem MenuID="2" Text="Web Applications"  URL="WebApplications.aspx"/>
    <MenuItem MenuID="3" Text="Portal" URL="Portal.aspx" />
    </Menu>

    <Menu MenuID="2" Text="Document">
    <MenuItem MenuID="4" Text="Tutorial" URL="Tutorial.aspx" />
    </Menu>

    <Menu MenuID="4" Text="Support">
    <MenuItem MenuID="5" Text="FAQs" URL="FAQs.aspx"  />
    <MenuItem MenuID="6" Text="Contact us" URL="ContactUS.aspx" />
     </Menu>

</Menus>
```

And my XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>


  <!-- Replace root node name Menus with MenuItems
       and call MenuListing for its children-->
  <xsl:template match="/Menus">
    <MenuItems>
      <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
    </MenuItems>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Allow for recursive child nodeprocessing -->
  <xsl:template name="MenuListing">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Menu">
    <MenuItem>
      <!-- Convert Menu child elements to MenuItem attributes -->
      <xsl:attribute name="Text">
        <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ToolTip">
        <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="NavigateUrl">
        <xsl:text>?Sel=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <!-- Recursively call MenuListing forchild menu nodes -->
      <xsl:if test="count(Menu) >0">
        <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
      </xsl:if>
    </MenuItem>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Help me in generating XML And binding it to the menu with XmlDataSource.

Comment: why are you using `xmlDataSource` why not other data source?

Comment: Actually I was asked not to use siteMaps, because Menu is different for each user. above shown image is of a Normal User. But for any user Menu and its Items should be displayed based on the ModuleID.

Comment: Thank you for editing @Mathias Muller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues with the xlst file:

1. While transforming the "Menu"s, children were not copied.
2. Transformed "Menu" attribute "NavigateUrl" should be like other
   MenuItem and it is "URL".
3. Transformed "Menu" attributes were wrong e.g. `<xsl:value-of
   select="Text"/>` should be `<xsl:value-of select="@Text"/>`.

Here's the xlst file that worked for me:

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace root node name Menus with MenuItems
       and call MenuListing for its children-->
  <xsl:template match="Menus">
    <MenuItems>
      <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
    </MenuItems>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Allow for recursive child nodeprocessing -->
  <xsl:template name="MenuListing">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Menu">
    <MenuItem>
      <!-- Convert Menu child elements to MenuItem attributes -->
      <xsl:attribute name="Text">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Text"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ToolTip">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="URL">
        <xsl:text>?Sel=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Text"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <!-- Recursively call MenuListing forchild menu nodes -->
      <xsl:if test="count(Menu) >0">
        <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
      </xsl:if>
    </MenuItem>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the markup I have used:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" BackColor="#0072c5"
    CssClass="Menu" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px"
    ForeColor="#F7F6F3" Width="100%" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Orientation="Horizontal"
    StaticDisplayLevels="1">
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" NavigateUrlField="URL" TextField="Text"/>
    </DataBindings>
</asp:Menu>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" DataFile="~/Default1.xml"   TransformFile="~/Default2.xslt" XPath="MenuItems/MenuItem" runat="server"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

I would suggest to use online xslt transformer to check the transformed xml. I found [this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) very helpful.